# Find and remove colon separated values (IPv6 addresses) from Python dictionary

Tags: python

I have a `json` (getting it using qemu guest agent) which I am converting to *python dictionary*, removing unwanted keys and then dumping back to `json`; now the challenge I am finding is in removing the 'key value' pairs where the values itself are `(:)` separated. I am sharing a sample `dictionary` after filter,

`{'return': [{'ip-addresses': [{'ip-address': '127.0.0.1'}, {'ip-address': '::1'}], 'name': 'lo', 'hardware-address': '00:00:00:00:00:00'}, {'ip-addresses': [{'ip-address': '192.168.10.34'}, {'ip-address': 'fe80::5054:ff:feef:75fd'}], 'name': 'eth0', 'hardware-address': '52:52:00:ef:35:fd'}, {'name': 'eth1', 'hardware-address': '52:51:00:1d:37:dd'}]}`

I want to get rid of the IPv6 address or any ip-address key whose value has (:) eg. `{"ip-address": "::1"}`. Please help me with ideas/solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def strip_ipv6(di):
    remove = []
    for k, v in di.items():
        if isinstance(v, list):
            for item in v:
                strip_ipv6(item)
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            strip_ipv6(v)
        if isinstance(v, str) and ':' in v and k.startswith('ip-address'):
            remove.append(k)
    for r in remove:
        del di[k]
```